# Block-diagonal Schur factorization in Python

Tags: python, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have a real non-diagonalizable matrix that I'm looking to decompose as tidily as possible. I would love to put it in Jordan normal form, but since that's problematic numerically I'm looking for the next best thing. I've discovered that there are FORTRAN and MATLAB routines that will do a block-diagonal Schur factorization of a matrix. The FORTRAN implementation in SLICOT is [`MB03RD`](http://slicot.org/objects/software/shared/doc/MB03RD.html) and the MATLAB implementation is [`bdschur`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bdschur.html) (which for all I know could just be a wrapper around `MB03RD`).

I don't have MATLAB on my computer, and the code that's generating my matrices is in Python, so I'm looking for an equivalent function in Python. Old documentation for Python Control Systems Library [indicated](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.0/matlab_strings.html#matrix-equation-solvers-and-linear-algebra) that an emulation of `bdschur` was planned, but it doesn't show up anywhere in the [current docs](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The Slycot repository has a FORTRAN [file](https://github.com/python-control/Slycot/blob/master/slycot/src/MB03RD.f) for `MB03RD`, but I can't seem to find much documentation for Slycot, and when I import it very few functions actually appear to be wrapped as Python functions.

I would like to know if anyone knows of a way to call an equivalent routine in Python, or if there exists some other similar decomposition that has an implementation in Python.

Comment: The interface to MB03RD looks reasonably simlpe (similar to LAPACK) and should be callable using f2py.

Comment: you are right about matlab's `bdschur` ir is a wrapper to `MB03RD` using `DTRSYL` from LAPACK

Comment: I don't think it is implemented in scipy either

Comment: I was hoping to not have to go the route of figuring out how to wrap it myself with something like `f2py`, but it looks like that might be the only way. My initial attempt to get `f2py` to wrap `MB03RD` seems to be falling flat with `ImportError: dlopen(...): Symbol not found: _ma02ad_` (where `MA02AD` is one of the external subroutines in `MB03RD`), so I may find myself opening another question before too long.

Comment: Have you considered SVD? numpy has that.

Comment: I have looked at the SVD of my matrix, but it doesn't quite tell me what I want to know. The matrix defines a linear differential equation, so the solution is the exponential of the matrix. Something like the Schur decomposition or Jordan normal form is nice because the outer matrices are inverses of one another, so one can focus on the matrix in the middle. The SVD gives different unitaries in my case, which makes it inconvenient for exponentiating.